# How to assign HTMLDocument into a JEditorPane to modify as source code?

Tags: java, swing, jeditorpane, dom

I'm wondering if it's possible to assign an existing `javax.swing.text.HTMLDocument` to a `JEditorPane` or a `JTextPane`, using the `setDocument()` method, but to show **source code** using code-completion and all that.  It should also allow modify it so synchronize 2 different views (I already have one jEditor to design).

How to assign `HTMLDocument` into a `JEditorPane` to modify as source code?

Comment: I'm sure it is possible. What kind of answer are you looking for?

Comment: thanks for reply... I'm looking for a single example or link to some document where I can read how to do it... I already done a lot of test, but I just can't do it work

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:
It does not use `setDocument()`, but will show the source code

```
 JTextPane jtPane = new JTextPane();
 StringBuilder st = new StringBuilder();
 String s;
 try {
 FileInputStream f = new FileInputStream("abc.html");
 BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(f));
 while((s=reader.readLine())!=null){
 st.append(s);
 }
 jtPane.setText(st.toString());
 } 
  catch (Exception e) 
   {
   e.printStackTrace();
}
```

This one uses `Document` and `setDocument()`:

```
String s;
Document doc = jp2.getDocument();
try {
FileInputStream f = new FileInputStream("abc.html");
BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(f));
while((s=reader.readLine())!=null){
doc.insertString(doc.getLength(), s+"\n", null);
}   
jtPane.setDocument(doc);
```

Comment: That's not exactly what I'm looking for... let me clarify: I already build a complex wysimolwyg editor (what you see, is more or less what you get)... and I already has done a code view for it, but to "synchronize" the two views, what I did was to just call setText() method, giving as parameter the complete html code, but doing so, I have 2 different document objects... at least... because every time I switch between "views", this method builds a new document object using the modified string... so, I've been trying to use the same document on both editors using one for display the source code.